# Cross validation when only the regression equation is given

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

Is there any function in R to conduct cross validation when you only know the regression equation?

Comment: What exactly would you cross-validate *with*?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is any function to do this in any language because it doesn't seem like it is possible to do.